# Syntax error: matching begin/end

Tags: verilog

```
module booth(num1,num2,prod);

input [22:0] num1,num2;
output [45:0] prod;
reg [22:0]num1_bar;
reg [46:0]sub_1;
reg [22:0]temp;
reg [22:0]result;
reg [1:0]sel;
reg [22:0]add;
reg [22:0]zeros;

assign temp = ~ num1;
assign num1_bar = temp + "00000000000000000000001";
assign sub_1 = {zeros[22:0], num2, "0"};

integer i;
always @* begin
    for( i = 0; i < 22; i = i+1) begin
        assign sel = sub_1[1:0];
        if(sel == "10") begin
            assign add = sub_1[46:24] + num1_bar;
            assign sub_1 ={add[22],add,sub_1[23:1]};
        end
        elseif(sel == "01") begin
            assign add = sub_1[46:24] + num1 ;
            assign sub_1 ={add[22],add,sub_1[23:1]};
        end
        else begin
            assign sub_1= {sub_1[46] ,sub_1[46:1]};
        end
    end

endmodule
```

I am trying to implement a floating point multiplier using carry look ahead adder and booth multiplier. After running the above code following errors has occurred only for the booth multiplier. 
Please help me out.

ERRORS:

> Summary Tue Apr 7 15:25:28 2015
>
> ---
>
> Summary New 
>   ERROR  ProjectMgmt:806 - "D:/XILINX PROGRAM/bth/booth.v" Line 45. Syntax error near "begin". 
>       ERROR  ProjectMgmt:806 - "D:/XILINX PROGRAM/bth/booth.v" Line 49. Syntax error near "else". 
>       ERROR  ProjectMgmt:806 - "D:/XILINX PROGRAM/bth/booth.v" Line 54. Syntax error near "endmodule". 
>       INFO  ProjectMgmt:1845 - Analyzing Verilog file "D:/XILINX PROGRAM/bth/booth.v" into library work

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `end` matching the `begin` of the `always` block.

*(Once you have fixed that, you will see that there are other errors, too. See mcleod_ideafix's answer.)*

Comment: Can please tell me where and how  to use the 'always ' block  in my code ?

Comment: You already have an always block: `always @* begin ...`, what is missing is one more `end`, right before `endmodule`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a confusion between VHDL and Verilog.

- Vector constants in Verilog are in the form: `Y'zXXXXXXX` where `Y` is the number of bits of the vector, `z` is the base (`b` for binary, `d` for decimal, `h` for hexadecimal), and `XXXX` is the constante value in the specified base.
- `else` `if` must separated

For example, the line:

```
if(sel == "10") begin
```

Must be rewritten as:

```
if(sel == 2'b10) begin
```

For large vectors, you can ommit the size specifier, and write the constant as this:

```
assign num1_bar = temp + 'b00000000000000000000001;
```

Comment: Large vectors should have the size specified, many simulators will infer 32 as the width if it not explicit. For this large vectors it is easier and more precise to write `23'b01`. `assign` should not be used inside an `always` block; the feature is being scheduled for depreciation.

Comment: I have rewritten the code for the booth multiplier but again there is some error in the last blocking assignment (prod = result) .Please help me sir .